# How to get realtime Python subprocess output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

Program that I'm trying to run using shell command, outputs one word per second. I'm trying to execute a shell command within Python script and get realtime output on each word that is outputed. All the other solutions I found online, don't actually print the realtime output but rather one finished line at the time. I want to get the **real** realtime output where each word is printed out in realtime rather than each line. This is the code that I've tried:

```
cmd=['slowprogram','-m', '15', '-l', '50']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line),
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

It waits until one line is finished and the prints it. Is there a way to get updates on and print each word in a line, in realtime?

UPDATE:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    for word in iter(line):
      print(word)
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

returns a bunch of numbers for some reason...:

```
111
117
108
100
32
104
97
118
101
32
115
97
```

How can I get each word from the line?

Comment: `p.stdout` is a [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object; syntactically you can read however you want from it as if it's a file. You might also want to look into the `bufsize` argument depending on your need.

Comment: @YiFei I tried iterating each word in a line but output was unexpected. I've updated my question, could you please take a look?

Comment: @YiFei I still can't figure it out. Could you please show how to read p.stdout in realtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it and it worked for me in a Linux shell. It uses an unbuffered IO object and prints out one character at a time. I'm quite sure there are better ways since I'm not an expert on either `subprocess` or event handling. You may also want to look into [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

```
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0) as p:
    char = p.stdout.read(1)
    while char != b'':
        print(char.decode('UTF-8'), end='', flush=True)
        char = p.stdout.read(1)
```

Comment: How can I save the output to an array without 'b' before each word? When I'm appending char variable to an array, 'b' is shown before each word.

Comment: To rephrase: how can I save the whole output to an array?

Comment: A little context: Python deals with two types of "string": byte string and "text" string. What we capture from `Popen` is a byte string and hence the `b`. Now byte strings can be converted to text strings by [decoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), and backwards by encoding.

Comment: I see. When I try to save the decoded chars to an array my words split up for some reason. ’Hello’ might turn into ’hel’ and ’lo’. Is there a way to save the whole output without rerunning the whole command?

Comment: Say you have a list (or any iterable for that matter) `L = ['hel', 'lo']`, you can use [`''.join(L)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). But depending on your need, you may as well save and append to a string from the beginning.

Comment: You are so very helpful. Last question: how can I write the output to a file? When I use: f = open('file','w')
         f.write(str(char.decode('UTF-8'))) It doesn't write anything to the file

Comment: IIRC, Python text files are by default uses line buffering, which means you have to `.flush()` it to actually write out the data. Note that files should be closed when done writing, and `f.close()` implies `f.flush()`. It is recommended to use a context manager (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase)) for such uses. Personally I also recommend to systematically look into Python and its standard library, which is extensive and extremely useful; pick up a book or go to Python's documentation - either would offer a nice top-down approach to programming.